# Executing console commands, Python

Tags: python, subprocess, blender, execution

I have a tricky problem that I can't seem to figure out on my own.

**[Goal]**

I have an automation script that has a button. When that button is pressed I run Blender in background mode, use a custom script that I wrote, and then exit Blender.

**[What I'm doing]**

So, I'm using subprocess's Popen to run everything but the issue occurs even if I directly run everything in CMD so the problem isn't in the way the subprocess call works. SO, for easier understanding, I'll be referring directly to the CMD method.
Step-by-step what I'm doing:

- I give a path to Blender's executable
- I give a path to a specific Blender scene to be opened
- I specify that I want Blender to run in background mode and to execute a Python script
- I give a path to the custom script (You can see it below)
- I give a path to a custom variable named "passed_object" that comes from the main automation script

The Custom script that I'm using is something like this:

```
import sys

def render(passed_object):
    # Doing Blender operations
    bpy.context.scene.custom_script.object_path = passed_object # I'm giving the passed_object variable to a Custom script in Blender

if __name__ == "__main__":
    args = sys.argv
    passed_object = args[-1]
    render(passed_object)
```

**[THE PROBLEM]**

So, running things as is in the CMD (or in the main automation script using subprocess) I get things done and the result is what I expect. The problem is that after everything's done, in the end I get an error saying that Blender can't open the file that's in the "passed_object" variable.

**[MY THOUGHTS]**

I think that CMD/subprocess is giving the passed_object variable to the Custom script as expected, but it also gives it directly to Blender when running it because I'm giving it directly when executing Blender. So, maybe there's a better way to do this and to pass the "passed_object" variable directly to the Custom script without also passing it to the Blender execution?

Comment: "in the end I get an error saying that Blender can't open the file that's in the "passed_object" variable." Okay, so that variable is a string, right? It comes from the command line that you typed, right? Did you check that you typed it correctly? Did you check that the file actually exists? Do you know *which folder* Blender will look in for the file? Do you understand what *relative and absolute paths* are?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I'll answer your questions 1 by 1: 1. Yes, the variable is a string. 2. I'm passing the string as an argument in the subprocess.Popen which is the same as just typing the string in the CMD. 3./4./5. Yes, it indeed IS typed correctly because the Blender Plugin that I'm passing it to uses it and does some renders based on it. 6. I know what's the difference between the two and I'm using an absolute path. The thing is that the path is correct and the plugin uses it, it's just that it should ONLY be used by the plugin and not Blender itself.